# Binary classification with Keras: poor performance

Tags: python, performance, classification, keras

I'm experimenting with Keras to develop a multi-layer perceptron for binary classification purposes and I'm surprised at the (poor) performance I obtain (57% accuracy on training set). A logistic regression correctly classifies 100% of the samples.

I created a data set with 2 inputs: input A is a sine function. Input B = input A plus a lag. When input A >= input B, output = 1. Otherwise, output = 0.

```
SIN SIN-1   Direction
0   0   1
0.06279052  0   1
0.125333234 0.06279052  1
0.187381315 0.125333234 1
0.248689887 0.187381315 1
0.309016994 0.248689887 1
0.368124553 0.309016994 1
0.425779292 0.368124553 1
0.481753674 0.425779292 1
0.535826795 0.481753674 1
0.587785252 0.535826795 1
0.63742399  0.587785252 1
```

The issue I have is similar to what is described in "Keras low accuracy classification task". The answer points in the direction of the data set which I do not believe is the problem here.

See code below. What am I missing to improve the accuracy of the model? Adding neurons to the layers or changing the activation function of the output layer to softmax hasn't yielded any better results.

```
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('SIN.csv', usecols=[0,1,2], engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values

X = dataset[:,0:2].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,2].astype(int)

# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(X) * 0.80)
test_size = len(X) - train_size
Xtrain, Xtest = X[0:train_size,:], X[train_size:len(X),:]
Ytrain, Ytest = Y[0:train_size], Y[train_size:len(Y)]


print(len(Xtrain), len(Xtest))

# create and fit Multilayer Perceptron model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=2, verbose=2)

# Estimate model performance
trainScore = model.evaluate(Xtrain, Ytrain, verbose=2)
print('Train Score: %.2f' % trainScore[1])
testScore = model.evaluate(Xtest, Ytest, verbose=2)
print('Test Score: %.2f' % testScore[1])
```

Comment: How many data points are you using to train this?

Comment: 117 training points. I forgot to mention that I also tried different optimizers to no avail.